# Asus RT-AC51U vs RT-N56U

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I'm in the process of getting a new router, and have a difficult time comparing the different models. Even from within the same brand, different models with similar features are priced quite differently. I'm not really sure what I get extra for the more expensive model.

In an attempt to understand this and turn it into a superuser-approved question. My question is for those two  Asus routers:

[RT-N56U](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/RTN56U/) and [RT-AC51U](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/RTAC51U/)

The N56U is the most expensive, but why? When comparing them, I only notice it has a extra usb port, range extender and medie bridge mode.

The AC51U is an AC router and seems to have more features such as guest-network.

Usually quality and price goes together, so what does the N56U offer

Comment: Even though you tried to make it more "SU approved", it is still a hardware recommendation and as you know those are off topic

Answer (score 1):

The N56U is a newer model that features much faster routing performance thanks to hardware NAT. The AC51U is likely mostly leftover supply that vendors are trying to get rid of. For most people, the two routers will perform about the same and it doesn't make that much difference. If you had really fast Internet access (over 60Mbps or so), you might appreciate the higher routing performance of the N56U.

Comment: Actually I think the AC51U are 3-4 years newer. I found them both on a site called: https://wikidevi.com.